# CMake cross compilation fails during linking stage on host (target is Raspberry Pi)

Tags: c, cmake, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

My source tree is

```
cpp
├── bin
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
├── headers
├── Makefile
├── TestConfig.h
├── TestConfig.h.in
├── README.txt
├── third_party
├── x_build
└── xtoolchain.cmake
```

I am using `crosstool-ng`.

**Edit:** Additional info (that may help others): I used reference of http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/  to boot RPI via QEMU (important resizing the img file to 8GB).

```
qemu-img resize 2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img +6G
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
- use "parted" or 'd' options to delete the 2nd partition and then recreate it but with a larger size. (don't worry, the data will remain). 1st partition is vfat.
- reboot to activate the partition changes.
- use "sudo resize2fs /dev/mmclk0p2" (or /dev/sda2 if symlink set in udev rules) to enlarge the root file system.
- use e2fsck -f /dev/mmcblk0p2 to perform a file system check.
```

Installed all `lib<package>-dev` and other libraries using `apt-get`. Then shutdown the QEMU

```
mkdir -p /tmp/rasp
sudo mount /home/test/raspberrypi/2014-01-07-wheezy-raspbian.img /tmp/rasp/ -o offset=$((122880*512))
cd $HOME/raspberrypi
sudo cp -ar /tmp/rasp ./rootfs
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER rootfs/home/pi
cd $HOME/raspberrypi/rootfs 

# also small hack around: error "Never use <bits/predefs.h> directly; include <stdc-predef.h> instead."
sudo cp /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include/features.h /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include/features.h-
sudo cp /home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include/features.h /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include
    sudo umount /tmp/rasp
```

I have also set up the target file system `/home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs` (This contains all the libraries necessary for cross compilation already installed)

The xtoolchain.cmake looks as follows

```
# ========================= CROSS COMPILATION INITIALIZATION BEGIN =======================
# this one is important
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
#this one not so much
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

# specify the cross compiler
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER
$ENV{HOME}/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
$ENV{HOME}/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-g++)

# where is the target environment
#SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
#/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs)


# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

#include_directories ("/home/test/local/raspidev/include")
# ========================= CROSS COMPILATION INITIALIZATION END =========================
```

The CMakeLists.txt (This is in addition to CMakeLists.txt in the parent directory as you can see from the file structure) portion inside the `src` directory looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
...
...
...
#Change 1 to 0 to disable logging
add_definitions(-DENABLE_LOG=1)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib:$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib:$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules)

#rdynamic is for stack unwinding on crash
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-W -O3 -g -Wall -std=c++0x -rdynamic -D_AIBTRACE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})

include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers")
#add_subdirectory (headers)
...
...
...
# ======================== SQLITE3 =================================

pkg_check_modules(SQLITE3 REQUIRED sqlite3)
include_directories(${SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
...
...  (...And other libraries)
```

I do an out of source build inside the `x_build` directory. as follows
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/test/xcompile/cpp/xtoolchain.cmake ../`

Strangely, it seems to be linking against the host libraries as opposed to the target libraries. `make VERBOSE=1` shows this

It throws linker error for all the libraries (These libraries are definitely present on the target system `rootfs`)

```
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
/home/test/local/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/lib/gcc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ldbus-1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am a bit lost.

Edit:

As requested here are few more things from `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set (SOURCES
file1.cc
file2.cc
main.cc
)

# Similarly, why not concise files grouping that will be reused ;)?
set (COMMONS_LIBS
${OpenCV_LIBS} 
pthread
${GLIBMM_LIBRARIES} 
${GTKMM_LIBRARIES} 
#${GSTMM_LIBRARIES}
${GSTREAMER_LIBRARIES}
${SQLITE3_LIBRARIES}
#${DBUS_GLIB_LIBRARY}
${DBUS_LIBRARIES}
${DBUS_GLIB_LIBRARIES}
${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES}
)

add_executable (
${EXE_DAEMON} 
${SOURCES} 
)

target_link_libraries( 
${EXE_DAEMON} 
$COMMONS_LIBS}
)

install (TARGETS 
${EXE_DAEMON} 
DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: Can you please show us full `ld` command?

Comment: @Peter does my edit help?

Comment: Can you paste here full link command (command that creates the errors you shown above), not CMakeLists.txt that creates it?

Comment: @Peter, found solution, see the answer. I was apparently missing some paths. These appear to be necessary apart from the listing on cross tool chain setup on cmake blog page.

Comment: Please don't add "[Solved]" to the title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. (And yes, it's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to CMakeLists.txt and then few more changes below and got it working!

```
include($ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/)
set(SYSROOT $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/)
set (PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR ${SYSROOT})
set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH ${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:${SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig)
#Change 1 to 0 to disable logging
add_definitions(-DENABLE_LOG=1)
find_program(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE NAMES pkg-config PATHS /usr/bin DOC "pkg-config executable" NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-W -O3 -g -Wall -std=c++0x -rdynamic  -D_TRACE ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"  CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
#rdynamic is for stack unwinding on crash
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib:$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib:$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH $ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules)

include_directories(SYSTEM
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/include
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/include
)

add_definitions(
-march=armv6zk 
-mfpu=vfp 
-mfloat-abi=hard
)

link_directories(

$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/lib
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib
$ENV{HOME}/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/local/lib
)   

set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

Then did the following

```
sudo vim /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so
```

edited

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread_nonshared.a )
```

to

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( libpthread.so.0 libpthread_nonshared.a )
```

similarly,

```
sudo vim /home/test/raspberrypi/rootfs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so
```

edited

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

to

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( libc.so.6 libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

Lastly, I added the `-lpcre` library to my `COMMON_LIBS`

Compile was successful. I then booted the raspberrypi via QEMU and used scp `scp daemon pi@<ip address>:~` to transfer the resulting binary to PI emulator and ran it. Tadaa!!! it works fine!